# How to Return DataTable from WebMethod using JSON and JQuery in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, asynchronous, datatable

I am new to `JSON`. I have created a sample which returns the `String` from `WebMethod` and assign the value returned to `asp.net Label` control.

**Sample JSON returning String:**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "JSONSample.aspx/DisplayData",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                //alert("hi");
                $("#ctl00_MainContent_lbltxt").text(data.d);
            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">

<label id="lbltxt" runat="server"></label>
</asp:Content>
```

**In .cs file( returning String):**

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string DisplayData()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

This works fine.

How to access `DataTable` using `JSON` and `JQuery`?

```
[WebMethod]
    public static DataTable DisplayData()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        return dt.GetData();
    }
```

I want to **return the DataTable and Bind the GridView/Access each row of `DataTable` using JSON & JQuery**. Please suggest me the right method to `Return` `DataTable` using `JSON`.

**I have seen some sample using `handlers` & some sample with using `WebMethod`. Which one to use?**

What are the Benefits one over the other.

Help Appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is how I normally do it. I load the `DataTable` contents into a dictionary, serialize it and everything works. You can modify the code to suit your needs.

```cs
[WebMethod]
public string GetQueryInfo()
{
    String daresult = null;
    DataTable yourDatable = new DataTable();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Tables.Add(yourDataTable);
    daresult = DataSetToJSON(ds);
    return daresult;
}

public string DataSetToJSON(DataSet ds)
{
    Dictionary < string, object > dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach(DataTable dt in ds.Tables) {
        object[] arr = new object[dt.Rows.Count + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++) {
            arr[i] = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray;
        }

        dict.Add(dt.TableName, arr);
    }

    JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return json.Serialize(dict);
}
```

**On your aspx.**

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'Webservices/GetQueryInfo',
    data: {},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        var objdata = $.parseJSON(data.d);
        // now iterate through this object's contents and load your gridview
    }
});
```

There are many tutorials on how to load a grid view using JavaScript or jquery. This will at least give you a starting point. You can find a nice example [here](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/03/bind-data-to-gridview-with-jquery-or.html).To do CRUD operations with the `GridView` see link [here](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1465/edit-delete-paging-in-gridview-using-jquery-simplemethod-part-1)

Comment: hi @Abide Masaraure, After making some modifications this code runs. But, i am not able to bind the GridView with this Returned DataTable will you please tell me how to do?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a link you can reference.What does your json returned object look like.Let me know if you cant still append rows to your grid view.

Comment: Oh..Till you reply me i have done with the same..! Now, How to Pass CommandName & CommandArguments?

Comment: I have send you a chat request on gmail.You need to clarify exactly what you want to do with those arguments.Bear in mind that, because you would have rendered the gridview client side,the server has no idea of the current viewstate of your gridview anymore.

Comment: Ok instead why dont we use http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/42333/asp-net-jquery?tab=general i have created it..so plz join here..

Comment: @AbideMasaraure ur link was very helpful to me +1